# SQL Server 2005 - Schema Ownership Stuck

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-permissions

I've created a database role in SS2005 and mistakenly made it the owner of the db_denydatareader schema. SSMS will not allow me to untick this option:

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198884/sql-server-2008-removing-schema-ownership) suggested that I change the ownership of that schema back to dbo (or whatever the default is for that database). However when I attempt to do that, it appears that it is already owned by dbo:

[image]

I've tried refreshing things, disconnecting/reconnecting, etc. Am I missing something? I'd just delete the role and start over but can't because it owns a schema!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh okay I figured it out. I was looking at the db_denydatareader **database role**, not the **schema**, when trying to restore the default owner. The schemas are found in a folder a little further down in SSMS:

[image]

Resetting the owner of the actual schema cleared that checkbox on the custom role. I feel a bit silly, but also feel like it would be a simple mistake that others might make as well, as the database roles match the schema names.